# Running a discord bot on startup on a raspberry pi B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, discord.py, python-3.7

I'm extremely new to Raspberry pi and I was looking to figure out how to launch a discord bot on startup when the pi first turns on. I looked this issue up on both this form and other places on the internet and found nothing or confusing results I don't really understand. I'm using Crontab -e to run my python3 program but regardless the file will not run.

This is what I have typed right now: .@reboot sleep 60 && python3 /home/pi/Desktop/MiniWeston/Mini_Weston2.py &

Other forms and videos tell me that this line of code should work but nothing has worked. If you're are wondering, I added the 'sleep 60' because some users said the problem was caused by the pi not connecting to the internet in time and in turn not connecting the bot successfully.

Help would be appreciated, I'm really lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had encoured the same issue crontab just wouldn't run my discord.py bot so what i did was to add it as a service, which you can learn more from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md).

Answer (score 0):

You could run `sudo raspi-config` and turn on auto-login to `pi` and wait for network at boot, and then edit `.bash_profile` with `nano .bash_profile` and append the bash you have from above to run the python file.